# jQuer Slick slider data get from Ajax with setInterval every second

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery slick to slide my text. Reference: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

And now I want the data dynamic get from database using jQuery Ajax Auto Refresh with `setInterval` every second.

JS

```
setInterval(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "test",
            type: "POST",
            data:
            {
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (jsonStr)
            {
                $('.card').empty();
                for(var i=0; i<jsonStr.runningText.length; i++)
                {
                    $('.card').append(jsonStr.runningText[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
```

test.php

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT * FROM tb_running_texts
");
while($dQ = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
{
    $runningText[] = $dQ['running_text'];
}

$data = array(
    "runningText"     => $runningText
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

and the JS slick

```
$('.lazy').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="lazy slider">
   <h1 class="card"></h1>
</div>
```

The current condition is all data will show directly. What I want is that data will show separately to slide.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood You right. You want to take only one record in each second, but not the same.

So first If You want to take every time different, then You need do like this:

```
    var offset = 0;
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "test",
            type: "POST",
            data:
            {
                offset: offset
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (jsonStr)
            {
                offset += 1;

                $('.card').empty();

                $('.card').append(jsonStr.runningText);

            }
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Then PHP

```
$offset = isset($_POST['offset']) ? $_POST['offset'] : 0;

$q = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT * FROM tb_running_texts ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET $offset
");

while($dQ = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
{
    $runningText[] = $dQ['running_text'];
}

$data = array(
    "runningText"     => $runningText
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

If You want to take every time random, then offset is not required, change line

```
SELECT * FROM tb_running_texts ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET $offset
```

To

```
SELECT * FROM tb_running_texts ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```